# Importance sampling on mixed normal distribution

Tags: r, distribution, gaussian, sampling, mixed-models

How do you compute the mean of a gaussian mixture model via importance sampling? Say i have a model such that there is a 60% chance of being sampled from a N(-1,1) distribution, and a 40% chance of being sampled from a N(2,1/9) distribution. Below is what i have from the standard importance sampling format of g*f(x)/h; but i do not think my function f is correct because I used a summation mix function instead of truly sampling through probability. Is there any suggestion on what I should change? thanks!

```
set.seed(100)
N = 100
x = rnorm(N,mean=0,sd=0.6) # Sample x samples from the proposal distribution h(x)
h = dnorm(x,mean=0,sd=0.6) # Evaluate h(x)
g = rep(0,N)
g=x


f = function(x) {        # Evaluate f(x)
  f = 0.6*rnorm(x,-1,1)+0.4*rnorm(x,2,1/9)
  return(f)
} 

mean(g*f(x)/h)
```

Answer (score 0):

For importance sampling, I guess there are several points that you should change in your code:

1. You may need a sufficient large `N`
2. You should use `dnorm`, rather than `rnorm` in your function `f`

An example is as below:

```
N = 1e8
X = rnorm(N) # Sample x samples from the proposal distribution h(x)
h = dnorm(X) # Evaluate h(x)


f = function(x) 0.6*dnorm(x,-1,1)+0.4*dnorm(x,2,1/9)      # Evaluate f(x)

mean(X*f(X)/h)
# [1] 0.2002296
```

As you can see, the theoretical mean of the mixed normal distribution is `0.6*(-1) + 0.4*2 = 0.2`, which is consistent to the result via importance sampling.

Comment: is it really sampling when we just using 0.6 and 0.4 as given? because we need sample() with prob=60% to sample to see how many percentage it is actually observed?

Comment: @jamesblack Yes, since the mean of mixed normal distribution is the weighted sum of means of all components